# Reverse ARP In Data Link Layer

Tags: network, networking, arp, network-theory

In the arp the Mac address is used as a broadcast address with a value FF:FF:FF:FF:FF:FF as the destination hardware address. But What about reverse ARP broadcast address? Which broadcast address should I use? Mac or IP address?

Comment: RARP is obsolete, replaced by DHCP.

Answer (score 1):

Reverse ARP used to require a server keeping track of the IP→MAC mappings. It's long been obsoleted by BOOTP in 1985 and subsequently by DHCP.

For completeness: IETF mentions ARP in their *link layer* section (anything below the network layer). RARP is put in the application layer - see [RFC 1122](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc1122). *Data link layer* is ISO/OSI parlance. In the OSI model, ARP should be associated with the network layer.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation sir